# Extra whitespace under the HTML tag

Tags: html, css

This is the website I am developing right now: [in-nabavi.com](http://farsi.in-nabavi.com/). There is nothing in it but a few blocks. As you see there is an extra white space at the end of the document that I really have no idea why it is in there.

This is the firebug result

[image]

As you see the area with red line around it is not included in the HTML area.

I also tried the following

```
body, html{
    margin:0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

but it didn't work again.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have used `content: "."` inside clearfix class for setting layout.
Use `content: "";` only.

```
.clearfix:after {
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   content: "";
   clear: both;
   height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a `.clearfix:after`css class in which there is a `content:"."`
Remove that.

Or override it, so that it does not hamper anything else.

Answer (score 1):

```
.clearfix:after {
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    content: close-quote;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this....

```
.panels-flexible-1 .panels-flexible-row-last{position: absolute;}
```